# Why does IsNull cause DIvide By Zero error?

Tags: sql-server

I have a CTE as part of a long stored procedure. I believe I have some sort of null propagation error. While trying to pinpoint the location of it I changed some code and that caused a divide by 0 error.

This works fine:

```
CalculatedMarks AS 
(
    SELECT SessionsId, CourseName, StudentName, NoMark, Present, Late, [Absent], TotalMarks, TotalMarksPerPerson,
      ISNULL( str( (( 1.0 * [Absent] / isNull(TotalMarksPerPerson, 1)    ) * 100), 3, 2), '')  + '/' 
    + ISNULL( str( (( 1.0 * Late / isNull(TotalMarksPerPerson, 1)    ) * 100), 3, 2), '')  + '/' 
    + ISNULL( str( (( 1.0 * Present / isNull(TotalMarksPerPerson, 1) ) * 100), 3, 2), '' ) + '/' 
    + str(TotalMarksPerPerson, 3, 2) AS Percentages
    FROM AllData
)
```

However, if I change the numerators (because maybe this is where the nulls come into play) as such

```
    CalculatedMarks AS (
      SELECT SessionsId, CourseName, StudentName, NoMark, Present, Late, [Absent], TotalMarks, TotalMarksPerPerson,
      ISNULL( str( (( 1.0 * isNull([Absent], 1) / isNull(TotalMarksPerPerson, 1)    ) * 100), 3, 2), '')  + '/' 
    + ISNULL( str( (( 1.0 * isNull([Late], 1)/ isNull(TotalMarksPerPerson, 1)    ) * 100), 3, 2), '')  + '/' 
    + ISNULL( str( (( 1.0 * isNull([Present], 1)/ isNull(TotalMarksPerPerson, 1) ) * 100), 3, 2), '' ) + '/' 
    + str(TotalMarksPerPerson, 3, 2) AS Percentages
    FROM AllData
)
```

I get a "Divide by Zero" error. I am really not sure what I am doing wrong especially because the numerator can't cause divide by zero errors. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Because zeroes aren't nulls. Maybe you mean `nullif(TotalMarksPerPerson, 0)`?

Comment: So what's the issue if the top query works fine?

Comment: The first one probably works because the numerator values are all null. Since nulls propagate the division is never actually attempted. Eliminating those nulls as in the 2nd query then exposes the divide by zero,

Comment: Could be that the absence of a isnull caused a short-circuit evaluation when one of the numerators had a null value, since the resulting operation would always be null. Then, by forcing it to 1, the whole expression had to be evaluated, resulting in divide by zero??

Answer (score 1):

The first one works when the numerator values are all null. Since nulls propagate the division is never "performed" and the denominator doesn't matter. Eliminating those nulls by wrapping the denominator in `isnull()`, as in the second query, then exposes the divide by zero.

To verify I've set up your queries with literal values here: https://rextester.com/DXZZFC20282

This is very similar to short-circuiting though I think there's a subtle distinction. In the past there have been a number of SQL Server "bugs" relating to unexpected behavior in `case` expressions, the lesson being that you can't always rely on a certain order of evaluation. In the case of null propagation `null / 0` is a defined result which isn't quite the same idea as skipping (or not skipping) a redundant step.

[SQL and the Snare of Three-Valued Logic](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/)

[Don’t depend on expression short circuiting in T-SQL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bartd/2011/03/03/dont-depend-on-expression-short-circuiting-in-t-sql-not-even-with-case/)

Comment: To answer the question of `null / 0` is similar to the analytic calculus needed to compute the indeterminate fraction `0/0`, and using the "unknown" interpretation of `null`, you cannot presume anything. If you know ahead of time how you *should* handle a null denominator case, maybe OP can use `ISNULL(NULLIF(value, 0), @appropriateReplacement)`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to check for null.

```
   / CASE WHEN isNull(TotalMarksPerPerson, 0) = 0 THEN 1 ELSE TotalMarksPerPerson END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
CalculatedMarks AS (
    SELECT 
        SessionsId, 
        CourseName, 
        StudentName, 
        NoMark, 
        Present, 
        Late, 
        [Absent], 
        TotalMarks, 
        TotalMarksPerPerson,
        (Case When TotalMarksPerPerson = 0 Then Str(0, 3, 2) Else Str(([Absent] / TotalMarksPerPerson) * 100, 3, 2) End) + '/' +
        (Case When TotalMarksPerPerson = 0 Then Str(0, 3, 2) Else Str(([Late] / TotalMarksPerPerson) * 100, 3, 2) End) + '/' +
        (Case When TotalMarksPerPerson = 0 Then Str(0, 3, 2) Else Str(([Present] / TotalMarksPerPerson) * 100, 3, 2) End) + '/' +
        Str(TotalMarksPerPerson, 3, 2) As Percentages

    From 
    (   
        SELECT 
            SessionsId, 
            CourseName, 
            StudentName, 
            NoMark, 
            IsNull(Present, 0) As Present, 
            IsNull(Late, 0) As Late, 
            IsNull([Absent], 0) As [Absent], 
            IsNull(TotalMarks, 0) As TotalMarks, 
            IsNull(TotalMarksPerPerson, 0) As TotalMarksPerPerson,
        FROM AllData
    ) 
)
```